# trouble making a decision on where to invest my time with big data analyses in R

Tags: r, data-analysis

I know R, I know SQL, I use Windows, I have a budget of $0, I have a terabyte of data, I have twelve processors, I have 96GB of RAM, I am motivated to learn new software if the speed gains will pay off in the long term.

I need to run descriptive statistics and regressions.

I have too many options.  Where should I devote all of my energy? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, but I am voting to close because this isn't a specific programming question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can ask here practical questions about coding, but discussions like this are alas out of scope for this site (see also [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: This is also Not Constructive in the sense that you are soliciting opinion. It will generate lots of different answers none any better than any other. See the [ask] section of the FAQ for details about what to ask etc on [so] and other SE sites.

Comment: @robjb if anywhere, it would fit at programmers.stackexchange.com. And even there they're likely to close this question as not suited.

Comment: Sorry about that - I guess there's no obvious answer :)  Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that *is* a big topic.

We did write a [survey paper of the *state of the art* of parallel processing with R](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v31/i01) which you could start with. While it is now three years old, large parts of the discussion still hold.

Otherwise, I would suggest starting small- to medium-size with something that actually matters to you and try to get that going faster.  Over at the [r-sig-HPC list (gmane link)](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.hpc) list many folks are happy to help with specifics.